# OpenSSL - how to get all settings when encrypting

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm using `openssl` to encrypt text with a vendor. I have to send test encrypted text and provide them with what they need to decrypt the text on their end. When I encrypt text and then try to decrypt it in [`Notepad++` using `Nppcrypt`](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/nppcrypt-notepad-plugin-to-encrypt-decrypt-files-selected-text/), it asks for options that I don't know were used when running `openssl`, so I can never decrypt the text.

What I basically run is something like:

`echo "test text" | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -k mypass -nosalt`

and then I cut and paste the output in Notepad++ and try to decrypt. But it asks options I don't know and as such, the decrypt fails. What other settings should I set in OpenSSL so that I can a.) decrypt in Notepad++ and share the info with my vendor?

Comment: You're [rolling your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). Why not use a more mainstream encryption, such as [Enigmail with Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/)?

Comment: What does it ask you? I guess it's related to password-based key derivation?

Comment: @SEJPM, there are a few choices that I know of; encoding (base 64), cipher (aes-128-cbc), salt/nosalt. Under key derivation there's PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc, authentication (add hmac?) and iv (random, key-derivation, zero). When I run the command in openssl to encrypt, I choose a password, cipher and no salt. But these other options that appear in Notepad++ I can't set when I run the command in openssl to encrypt.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff, that won't work for us. We have to send files to a vendor with some rows encrypted and some rows in plain text. This is part of a software package that's being developed. Besides, we're using aes-128, how does this mean we're rolling our own crypto?

Comment: @Tensigh: "Rolling your own crypto" doesn't just mean the algorithms, but also how they're used – the cipher itself (some think DES is strong), cipher mode (CBC is alright, but many foolishly choose ECB), key derivation, even final framing (`openssl aes` doesn't just output _raw_ encrypted data, but in a special format)...

Answer (score 2):

## No Can Do

NppCrypt does not support OpenSSL's key derivation function.

OpenSSL uses its [own homebrew key derivation function](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase).

And NppCrypt only supports some more standard mechanisms (`pbkdf2`, `bcrypt`, `scrypt`):

[image: Screenshot of nppcrypt's "key-derivation" tab]
`

#### Alternatives?

I don't know. But [Thomas Pornin suggests GnuPG as superior to OpenSSL in another question regarding OpenSSL's weird key derivation choices](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23230/i-dont-see-how-salt-in-the-openssl-command-line-tool-enhances-security-at-al).

Comment: I'd suggest GnuPG as well, if at least for using a well-documented output format.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff, thank you. I was not aware of those limitations/quirks of OpenSSL. I'll look into GnuPG.